# Saving data in html form when form validation error occures

Tags: html, forms, validation, viewstate

i am facing a problem that i am having a long registration form in PHP, so the problem is that when some validation error occurs with any particular field then all the details of other  fields get vacant as well and this is not an efficient way to work.
So what i want is looking for some kind of solution that the user **should only re-enter password in case of making any mistake and rest of form value must be there.**
I am using PHP, HTML for development.

Comment: i think you can do it using session

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you have already values in the different fields of the form every time you generate the form, and set the value in the html input. You can do that as follow assuming you use POST:

```
<input type="text" name="var" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['var']) ? $_POST['var'] : ''); ?>"/>
```

Here you check if $_POST['var'] has a value (`isset($_POST['var'])`). If so, you write its value (`$_POST['var']`), else, you write nothing (`''`)

You can use this method to adapt it to any kind of input.

Comment: Thank you sir its working !! but is there any solution like viewstate in asp.net as it is an easy option. Thanks again

Comment: @user2681730 I don't know about asp.net, sorry. But this solution is quite simple I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to store variables too don't forget the  isset($_SESSION['var'])
can be used. and once set they can be used anywhere to it. BTW stratfords answer is way better. easy and quick.